# NHibernate erro no group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Estou estudando `NHibernate` e está me dando um erro no `group by`, 
porém a principio está me gerando errado o `sql`, não sei porque, segue o código abaixo da SQL e sua estrutura.

```
string hql = "select p.Categoria, count(p) " +
                   "from Produto p " +
                   "group by p.Categoria";

IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
var resultados = query.List<Object[]>();
```

E a estrutura das classes está assim:

```
public class Produto 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Preco { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; } 
}

public class Categoria
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

O sql gerado pelo NHibernate:

```
select
        produto0_.CategoriaId as col_0_0_,
        count(produto0_.Id) as col_1_0_,
        categoria1_.Id as id1_2_,
        categoria1_.Nome as nome2_2_
from
        Produto produto0_
inner join
        Categoria categoria1_
            on produto0_.CategoriaId=categoria1_.Id
group by
        produto0_.CategoriaId
```

Porém está me retornando o erro abaixo:

> 'could not execute query
>   [ select produto0_.CategoriaId as col_0_0_, count(produto0_.Id) as col_1_0_, categoria1_.Id as id1_2_, categoria1_.Nome as nome2_2_ from Produto produto0_ inner join Categoria categoria1_ on produto0_.CategoriaId=categoria1_.Id group by produto0_.CategoriaId ]
>   [SQL: select produto0_.CategoriaId as col_0_0_, count(produto0_.Id) as col_1_0_, categoria1_.Id as id1_2_, categoria1_.Nome as nome2_2_ from Produto produto0_ inner join Categoria categoria1_ on produto0_.CategoriaId=categoria1_.Id group by produto0_.CategoriaId]'

Ao meu ver, o `SQL` do `group by` deveria também informar as colunas da categoria, por isso está dando erro, mas não consegui descobrir porque não está gerando.

Comment: já tentou explicitar os campos?

Comment: Explicitando os campos no select e no group by ai da certo, mas a idéia é nao precisar explicitar visto que se houve um aumento de campos, siga funcionando de forma automatica.

Comment: Ai você está programando errado Matheus porque está criando um mau desempenho na sua SQL que é na maioria dos sistemas o grande gargalho ... Essa é a minha visão mediante experiência, pra que selecionar campos que não serão usados? Outra coisa se o algoritmo for ruim do Hibernate? rapaz são tantas vertentes... que na minha experiência gosto de ter o dominio do código

Comment: verdade, estás correto em relação a isto. Mas mesmo assim deveria funcionar pois em teoria deveria me retornar um objeto do tipo categoria com todas as informações da categoria.

mas obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Certo eu posso até concordar mas, eu não vi na documentação que isso é assim, se achou algo?